# XPath - Discard Certain Table Rows

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm using PHP DOM and DOMXPath class.
This is what I have in essence:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div> More data </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div> More data </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div> More data </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div> More data </div></td>
    </tr>
    // I want all of these removed
    <tr>
        <td class="className"></td> // Nothing between <td> tags here
    </tr>
    // Repeat N times
    .
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

This is a pattern of rows and repeats plenty of times.

What I want is an XPath expression which will get me all the rows but discard every row like the last one in this example.

To be clear: not the last row only but discard every row which meets some criteria and return others.

Comment: You forgot to add your `PHP DOM and DOMXPath` code.

Comment: I have used DOM to select the appropriate table so this code is not the issue. I don't have any DOMXPath code because I don't know what to write to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `normalize-space()` to filter out empty nodes, for example :

```
/table/tr[normalize-space(.)]
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Can I somehow by any chance use <td> class attribute to filter out the row? And what is the best on line resource for learning XPath (in your opinion)? W3CSchools is not to descriptive and not many examples.